# Setting cookie using javascript and reading it on server side

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net

I am using cookie and I am setting its value like this,

```
document.cookie = 'province=Alberta; expires=Fri, 3 Dec 2014 20:47:11 UTC; path=/'
```

And I am trying to read it on my server side like following

```
if (Response.Cookies["province"].Value != null)
```

But the  `Response.Cookies["province"].Value` is giving me null.

What may the reason for this?

Comment: Surprising that search engine you are using did not give any links. Consider Bing - [C# read cookie](http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+read+cookie). (I work for Microsoft, so mentioning Bing, C# and MSDN could be considered advertisement, in this case use Google link - to search https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+read+cookie )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to look in the request, not the response. The request is what is sent to the server. The response is what you send to the client. For example:

```
string cookieValue = string.Empty;

if (Request.Cookies["province"] != null)
{
    cookieValue = Request.Cookies["province"].Value.ToString();
}
```